# how many ways to do programming in Excel . except for VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to manipulate data in excel with some complex functions.
It seems that I have to use VBA.

However I don't want to learn it.
Is there any other way to do programming in the excel? Some language like C#?

I don't want to create a independent C# application using some interface provided by Excel. Only program in excel, like VBA, but a different language.

Comment: Considering that you have unlimited rows and columns, and you have AND and OR functions, I'm sure you can implement a Turing machine within a spreadsheet.  Which implies you can program anything, any way you want.

Comment: This isn't an appropriate programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to create a independent C# application using some interface provided by Excel. Only program in excel, like VBA, but a different language.

You **cannot** unfortunately. To program **in** Excel from within Excel you will have to learn VBA.

To program for Excel, be it VBA, VSTO(C#, VB.Net) you need to understand the Excel Object Model (**EOM**) without which you cannot do programming for Excel.

You don't need to learn VBA per se if you want to develop Office solutions from C# but as you become familiar with the EOM, you will notice that you automatically develop an understanding for VBA.

**EDIT**

[Excel Object Model from Excel's perspective](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068.aspx)

[Excel Object Model Overview from VS's perspective](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Yup. But it will still mean that you have to use VBA

Comment: In some (rare) situations no - for specific tasks you could invoke XLM in range names.

Comment: Correct again :) But then I hardly consider that "Programming" :-D

Answer (score 1):

You can develop Excel "Add-Ins" in C# using VSTO - Visual Studio Tools for Office ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx)).

This is not truly "inside Excel," but once installed your add-in can run without having to start up any external application.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a VBA editor built in to use VBA only. 
If you want to use another language it would need to be external.

While you could make a C# add in, this is not in the built in editor as you described.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you simply cannot do this right now. In Office 15 it looks as though you'll be able to use JS:

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-to-focus-on-html5-and-javascript-for-office-15-extensions/10266