# C# in Excel avoiding VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vba

is there a way to use C# in Excel? I mean using C# to automatize excel spreadsheet doing what it is already possible with the VBA editor. I usually use excel for my job tasks but the only programming language I know is c# and I don't want to start with VBA now.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-excel?view=vs-2019

Comment: Probably debatable, but I think you can summarize the discussion to "no you can't". Cf. posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856888/how-many-ways-to-do-programming-in-excel-except-for-vba?rq=1 and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634126/can-we-write-a-macro-in-c-sharp-for-excel

Comment: You can automate Excel from the *outside* using Office Interop. The API is the same whether you use VBA or Office interop which means you can record a macro with the steps you want, inspect the calls and make the same ones in C#

Comment: IMHO, VBA is not a complicated language and learning it isn't difficult if you know how to code.  But Excel VBA is far more about the Excel object model and that is where you will need to spend most of your time.  Like most people who are Excel VBA experts, I still like the ability quickly record a macro to see how to do something then rewrite the code properly.  You can't really do that using VSTO.

Answer (score -2):

Try this library :[ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)

You can almost do everything on that library, and you don't need to have office installed.

Comment: The OP didn't ask how to create Excel files, the question was how to automate Excel